# opencv cv::imshow access violation error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to using OpenCV. I'm trying to convert a double type matrix to an image, like using imagesc function in MATLAB. I know that we can use imshow to do that. But it shows 'Access Violation' error when I tried to use a matrix of size 600 * 900. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8 with OpenCV 2.4.5 .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuda_runtime_api.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int iter1;
    float *A;
    A=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 50 * 50);
    for(iter1=0; iter1<(50 * 50); iter1++)
    {
        A[iter1] = iter1;
    }
    cv::Mat test(50, 50, CV_32F, &A);
    cv::imshow("test", test);
    cv::waitKey();
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

The above is the code I used for producing an image out of 50 * 50 matrix which worked fine. Kindly let me know if you find the problem with bigger matrix or give me some sample code if you have any.

Comment: cv::Mat test(50, 50, CV_32F, &A); // you want to pass A, not &A (which is a float**)

Comment: Berak, one more question. Do we have to convert float values to CV_8UC1 values? Because even after applying colormap I only see a white screen. This is my modified code:

Comment: cv::Mat test(50, 50, CV_32FC1, A);cv::Mat test2;
 cv::applyColorMap(test, test2, 3);
 cv::imshow("test", test);

Comment: yes. you will have to convert it for that. test.convertTo(test,CV_8U, scalefactor); // unsure about the factor, CV_8U is [0..255]. your range is *what* ? (50*50 will still fit in, but 600*900 ? do your own maths here